# jQuery using wildcards for CKEditor plugin to replace editor with textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

in `jQuery` we can use `wildcards` such as `*,?` or `$` to get all elements which we used in `html` for example:

```js
$("[id^=_TextEditor]")
```

now in my html code i have multiple `textarea` that i want to replace them with `jQuery CKEditor`, here all of `id`s make automatically and i know end of them only, like with pasted code above `_TextEditor`,how can i use this jquery wildcard for `ckeditor`? for example:

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace("[id^=_TextEditor]", {
            height: '200px',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `each` loop and extract specific instance ids inside the loop

```
$("[id^=_TextEditor]").each(function(){
     CKEDITOR.replace(this.id, {
         height: '200px',
     });
})
```